# reading DateTime formats in AzureDataFactory (V2)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I was looking for information on which types of datetime formats are supported in Azure Datafactory.
It seems that the format dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt is not recognized as valid.
When i send a file with 05-05-2020 7:00 pm it gives:

> "errorCode": "2200",
>       "message": "Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidDataValue,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column 'ETA' contains an invalid value '05-05-2020 8:00 pm'. Cannot convert '05-05-2020 8:00 pm' to type 'DateTime' with format 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.,Source=mscorlib,'"

What am i doing wrong here?